# Is possible to have an event linked to object's own parameter?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, kineticjs

I have an object (lets say a circle) with specific parameters (x,y and radius).

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        radius: 20
}
```

The radius of the circle is thereafter dynamically changed by the user.
Now I want a listener that continuously observes the radius, and every time the radius goes below 5, it deletes the circle. Something like:

```
circle.on("radiusLessThanFive",function (e) {
this.remove();
}
```

So how do I configure this `radiusLessThanFive` event that constantly listens to the radius of the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unfortunately, there isn't something built in that would do that. So you just have to make it part of your application logic.

Let's say you have a layer called shapesLayer. You can do:

```
function radiusLessThanFive(){
    var circles = shapesLayer.get('.circle'); // I can't remember the getting all circles syntax, but something like this
    for ( var i=0; i<circles.length; i++) {
        if(cicrles[i].getRadius() < 5 ){
            circles[i].remove();
            shapesLayer.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

While this is not the most efficient solution ever, it gets the job done... unless you know how to create your own custom events in javascript (which would have to do the same thing as the above function anyways).

In case you'd like to take the custom event road, here is a link: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/

Edit: regarding comment below

```
function radiusLessThanFive(myCircle){ //function which checks radius of single circle and deletes if less than 5
        if(myCircle.getRadius() < 5 ){
            myCircle.remove();
            myCircle.getParent().draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a separate function to constantly check if all circle radius are below 5, isn't it possible to have that code inside of the function where you allow the user to edit the radius? So for example, when the user is decreasing the radius, have an if block to see if the radius is below 5, and if so, just delete it then and there.
Would that work?

Comment: Yes, that would work just fine. All you have to do is modify the above function so that it does the job for a single circle by passing a the circle as an attribute in the function and checking its radius.  I wrote the function above to take into account dynamic creation of circles and in the case that the events that change the radius are not user events directly on the circle, like animations. If you are animating a circle and there is logic which changes its size then you would have to run the function to check as the user is not directly acting on the object.

Comment: Currently my code has a similar logic as explained by you. I liked the idea of creating custom events as mentioned by you, but since IE9 and below dont support it, still some time to go before I will use it.  Tks.